# Horizontal bar chart with plotly.express not showing all data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly-express

I have a dataframe with 4 columns and 20 entries. When I run my plotly express code, it only shows the first 4 entries. I have searched up and down, but have not as yet found a solution for this specific problem. Here's the code:

```
top20_cat_chart = px.bar(x=top20_merged.cat_prize,
                        y=top20_merged.birth_country_current,
                        color=top20_merged.category,
                        orientation="h",
                        title="Top 20 Countries by No. Prizes & Category")

top20_cat_chart.update_layout(xaxis_title="No. Prizes",
                             yaxis_title="Country")

                          
top20_cat_chart.show()
```

I have searched the plotly documentation, stackOverflow, and elsewhere, to no avail.

What I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgu5F.png)

What I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGHyf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I had to display 46 variables horizontally but it was cropped.

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis={"dtick":1},margin={"t":100,"b":100},height=900)
```

This is what I used, my y-axis was cropped I used the option **"dtick":1** it displays all the rows, you can play around with margin and height according to your needs.